# Post on Reddit using java API

Tags: java, reddit, jreddit

I want to post on Reddit using java API.

I have created a username and password on Reddit and I have created an authentication token for the application.

I tried Jreddit but its one year old repo and I was unable to find the way to post using Jreddit.

Can anyone suggest how to do it may be via java or javascript.

Comment: What research have you done into available API's or methods of posting, and what have you tried that has worked/not worked?

Comment: I had used Jreddiet java API but it has method submitLink method from SubmitActions class that takes five parameters.I am unable to understand significane of last two parameters in this method

Comment: Also tried JRAW.Added in pom.xml
<dependency>
<groupId>net.dean.jraw</groupId>
<artifactId>JRAW</artifactId>
<version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency> 
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.dean.jraw:JRAW:jar:0.8.0: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer net.dean.jraw:JRAW:pom:0.8.0 from https://maven.elasticsearch.org/releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of elasticsearch-releases has elapsed or updates are forced.

Comment: I tried RedditJerk But it requiers java8 but my system supports upto java 7